# Jquery displaying id to html and removing when unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the id of a selection onto the page and then remove it when it unselected. It does display the selected id, but when I click the same seat to unselect it, it just puts the id up again. I think its a problem with the tempArray.pop.

JQuery

```
 $(this).each(function() {
     // Getting the id of each seat
     var seatLocation = $(this).attr('id');
     // If seatLocation is not inArray - add it - else - pop it off 
     //$.inArray take (value , name of array)
     var index = $.inArray(seatLocation, window.tempArray);
     if (index = -1) { // -1 is returned if value is not found in array
         window.tempArray.push(seatLocation.replace('_',''));
     } else {
         window.tempArray.pop(seatLocation.replace('_',''));
     }
     // Show the ids in a span to the users4
     console.log(window.tempArray)
     // join() converts an array to a string, putting the argument between each element.
     $('#seatLocation').html(window.tempArray.join(', '));
    });
```

HTML to display the seat id

```
<div id='ticket-options'>
    <label>Seats</label>
    <span id="seatLocation"></span>
    <label>Passengers</label>
    <span id='seatsChosen'>0</span> of <span id='numSeats2'>4</span>
</div>
<div class="legroom">
```

HTML of tables with id

```
<table>
<tr class="row1">
  <td class='n' id='1_A'>T</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_B'>F</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_C'>T</td>
  <td class="row_num">1</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_D'>T</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_E'>F</td>
  <td class='n' id='1_F'>T</td>
  <td>Extra Legroom</br>£13.99</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This is an image of the results I get when I select the same seat repeatedly.

[image]

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? Can you setup a working example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two event on the same element.

Add a `event.stopPropagation();`

Cause the select and unselect are on the same event.

Add this in your function and try... Hope it work for you.

Comment: Where should I add it? Thanks

Comment: I think in your event click for delete. You must add your event in parameter of your function click(function(event))